# How to benchmark mongo engine itself, without interfering with a driver?

Tags: mongodb

I am optimising a bunch of server machines to be hosting MongoDB. I need to get a feeling of whether the optimisations are effective or not, from the perspective of Mongo engine.

To reduce noise, I would preferably not to use a Mongo driver to eliminate its interference.

How is it feasible to carry out such benchmark?

Could "[JS benchmarking harness](http://www.mongodb.org/about/contributors/js-benchmarking-harness/)" be useful for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general server optimisation, your best starting point is the [Production Notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/) section in the MongoDB manual. A careful read will help avoid some common mistakes such as not increasing the [`ulimit` settings](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/) or not [disabling NUMA](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/#production-numa) on Linux servers.

There is also a very detailed section on [Security](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/security/) including access control, network exposure, firewalls, and other relevant configuration.

> To reduce noise, I would preferably not to use a Mongo driver to eliminate its interference.

You can't avoid using a driver; even the `mongo` shell is effectively a JavaScript shell sending commands via the C++ driver.  Given there can be some differences in the driver implementations (for example: approaches to connection pooling, timeouts, and defaults), I would suggest choosing whatever driver you expect to be most commonly used in your environment and use that as a reference point for relative performance on your server changes.

> Could "JS benchmarking harness" be useful for this scenario?

As noted in the MongoDB documentation page you linked:

```
This benchRun command is designed as a QA baseline perf measurement tool, not designed
to be a "benchmark".
```

A good indication of whether your tuning is successful would be to run against a representative workload from your application(s). Even if you've followed best practice for server configuration, applications can still experience performance problems from design issues (poor schema choices, overuse of server-side JavaScript, missing indexes, etc).

I would suggest setting up a monitoring service that supports MongoDB and make sure you capture a reasonable amount of metric history so you can compare the outcome for similar workloads before and after tuning parameters.  A common choice is the free [MMS Monitoring service](https://mms.mongodb.com/) from MongoDB, Inc. There are a number of other admin & monitoring services/tools listed in the [Admin UIs](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/) section in the documentation.